# Django admin - jQuery namespace

Tags: jquery, namespaces, django-admin

I'm trying to use certain jQuery plugins in my Django admin site.

Django admin sets the jQuery namespace to `django.jQuery` (to avoid conflicts)

If I don't have the default `$` namespace for jQuery, the plugins won't work, will they ?

Do I have to do something like

```
window.$ = django.jQuery
```

?

How & where can I change this namespace for the whole admin site ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, most plugins will require "jQuery" - not $ - to be available, and then provide $ themselves as in dmidz's answer.

Therefore, insert

```
var jQuery = django.jQuery;
```

before your external references. If you're loading a bunch of thirdparty jQuery plugins, put the above line in a script tag that preceeds the plugins.

See also my question five months ago [How to provide $ to third-party, external jQuery plugins in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484547/how-to-provide-to-third-party-external-jquery-plugins-in-django-admin)

Comment: I actually ended up having to do both `var jQuery = django.jQuery;` and `var $ = django.jQuery;`. Thanks

Comment: also. beware. if another plugin already included it's own jQuery, you'll overwrite it, and end up in disaster, as the other plugin will now be lost...jquery.noConflict to the rescue, but always getting me headaches, just thinking about it...but yes, this solution will work, in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to leave the jQuery in django.jQuery namespace wich is a good idea when using cms with different modules that could conflict.
But you wrap your plugin within such :

```
;(function($){
  // here $ is only in this scope and so totally inobrusive
  // plugin code
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: This can work but you have to do that each time you add a plugin or update it... :(

Answer (score 2):

Someone else had a similar problem and used the deconflict function: http://www.lokkju.com/blog/archives/143

I'm not sure what version Django uses, but I think the point of using the django namespace is that it can use its own version of jQuery for its internal operations, but still let you use a different version for your own work.

Comment: Finally I used my version of jQuery because I didn't succeed to make namespace renaming after spending an hour on it. Thanks anyway.